# Tax Calculation for 2019 Self Employed

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, self-employment, hsa

Currently, I am self employed and I am going to file tax with my spouse. I have below questions on self employment tax.

1. Do I need to pay 15.3 percent social and medicare self employment tax before or after 25% of self employment contribution?
2. I need to pay self employment tax (15.3%) and federal tax (22%). Do I need to pay state tax apart from this one?
3. My spouse has insurance and invested in HSA. Can I contribute to HSA as well?

Comment: "Do I need to pay state tax apart from this one?" Only if your state has an income tax and you meet the income threshold.

Comment: By “self-employment contribution”, do you mean a contribution to a retirement account? If so, can you be more specific about the type of retirement plan?

Comment: The best way to answer this would be to just read the instructions for Schedule C and SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The State tax would be 100 multiplied by .028 to get $2.8
- The Federal Tax would be 100  multiplied by .0996 to get $9.96
- The self employment tax would be  100 multiplied by  .1413 to get $14.13
- The sep contribution would be 100 -(14.13/2) multiplied by .16667 to get $15.47